# Prevent overlap of views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgrectintersectsrect

I have an array of subviews of my container view, added programmatically setting the frame manually.
When the user select a filter I would like to zoom the selected views (matching the filter) increasing their size by 1.1 and maintaining the center but preventing the overlap. 
Here's my code so far:

```
- (void) positionSubviewsWithoutOverlapping: (NSArray *) views {
    for (UIView *v in views){
        CGPoint center = v.center;
        v.frame = CGRectMake(v.frame.origin.x, v.frame.origin.y, v.frame.size.width*1.1, v.frame.size.height*1.1);
        v.center = center;
    }
    while ([self repositionSubviews:views]) {
    }
}

- (BOOL) repositionSubviews: (NSArray *) views{
    BOOL somethingChanged = FALSE;
    for (UIView *v1 in views){
        for (UIView *v2 in views){
            if (v1 != v2){
                if (CGRectIntersectsRect(v1.frame, v2.frame)){
                    somethingChanged = TRUE;
                    [self preventOverlapOfView1:v1 View2:v2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return somethingChanged;
}

- (void) preventOverlapOfView1: (UIView *) v1 View2: (UIView *) v2  {
    if (CGRectGetMaxX(v1.frame) > CGRectGetMinX(v2.frame)){
        CGFloat diff = CGRectGetMaxX(v1.frame)-CGRectGetMinX(v2.frame);
        v1.frame = CGRectMake(v1.frame.origin.x-diff, v1.frame.origin.y, v1.frame.size.width, v1.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if (CGRectGetMinX(v1.frame) < CGRectGetMaxX(v2.frame)){
        CGFloat diff = CGRectGetMaxX(v2.frame)-CGRectGetMinX(v1.frame);
        v2.frame = CGRectMake(v2.frame.origin.x-diff, v2.frame.origin.y, v2.frame.size.width, v2.frame.size.height);
    }
    if (CGRectGetMaxY(v1.frame) > CGRectGetMinY(v2.frame)){
        CGFloat diff = CGRectGetMaxY(v1.frame)-CGRectGetMinY(v2.frame);
        v2.frame = CGRectMake(v2.frame.origin.x, v2.frame.origin.y-diff, v2.frame.size.width, v2.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if (CGRectGetMinY(v1.frame) < CGRectGetMaxY(v2.frame)){
        CGFloat diff = CGRectGetMaxY(v2.frame)-CGRectGetMinY(v1.frame);
        v1.frame = CGRectMake(v1.frame.origin.x, v1.frame.origin.y-diff, v1.frame.size.width, v1.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

The problem is in `- (void) preventOverlapOfView1: (UIView *) v1 View2: (UIView *) v2`, I should use `CGRectIntersection` but I can't figure out how to use it.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly leftfield suggestion, why dont you just use a UICollectionView?  Its designed precisely for the type of application you are suggesting.  You can zoom in a certain cell and it will automatically move the other cells around to accomodate the change in size.

If not, then I would suggest you use autolayout for this.  That again will better help other views not to overlap.  But the collection view would be the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately I cannot use UICollectionView, the views are loaded using the SVGKit library from a map of a floor that is basically an svg file. I have to zoom the rooms of the map selected from the filter.

Comment: Your use of CGRectIntersectsRect looks ok to me.  Am afraid Im not sure what the issue is, good luck :(